# how to set the title of tabbaritem on UITabController

Tags: iphone

I try to set the title of tababritem on UITabController for multi-language using

```
self.viewControllers[0].title=  NSLocalizedString(@"myTitle",@"")  ;
```

But it reports title is not themmeber of nsarray.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 2):

You can't access elements of an NSArray using square brackets.
Here's the code you'll need

```
UIViewController *theViewController = (UIViewController *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
theViewController.title =  NSLocalizedString(@"myTitle",@"");
```

Comment: error: request for member 'title' in it something not a structure or union